# How to protect NTC thermistors for embedding in cement?

Tags: thermistor, environmental-sealing

My kitchen at ground floor already has a floor (with floor heating) but it needs to be lifted by 3-5 mm with a very fine cement, on top of which tiles will be installed.

I would like to embed a couple of NTC thermistors in it (likely both at the center) to eventually make measurements of the temperature and to estimate losses to the ground, and so on. I'd put more than one to compare values, but all next to each other.

I thought about NTC because they are thinner and because I'll need quite some of them for the other parts of the ground floor.

How should I protect the NTC? I thought about heat shrink and some silicone sealant, nothing more, since no humidity is expected (after drying) and because the expected temperature rage will never be wider than 0°C - 55°C.

Am I correct? How should I protect the thermistor(s) before embedding in the fine cement?

Comment: I think one question that you might want to ask yourself first is what you are trying to protect them against. Often NTCs are embedded in epoxy for other applications (e.g. automotive). Might be something to consider as well. As an alternative, though... Do you have the option of carving a channel to replace the thermistors in case they fail/break/deteriorate, as opposed to sealing them in cement forever?

Comment: The idea is to protect them from the initial humidity and liquid cement, and from the curing of the cement. I cannot place a small channel, since the whole idea is recent and the floor heating has already been laid.

Answer (score 2):

There are at least two main considerations:

1. Protection against chemical effects. Some materials such as Portland cement are very high pH (alkaline) and that could attack the materials in the sensor. That also means that they are quite conductive in the presence of moisture. Since  you're probably using a high resistance thermistor, leakage could affect the reading, disproportionately so at lower temperatures.
2. Protection against physical damage. The thermistor disk or bead is brittle under the (usually epoxy) coating. When the cement shrinks, creeps or flexes under pressure from outside it can transmit enormous forces to the sensor which could cause errors or damage the sensor. Silicone helps, but it is not compressible.

Since you have such a thin layer it is difficult to protect the wire and sensor within that layer. You may be able to cut a deeper channel into the floor with a "diamond channel cutter" and insert a tube, however you will have to **ensure there is sufficient thickness left** over the water tubes or whatever is heating your floor.

[image]

Comment: I could prepare a 1-2 mm deep channel from the sensor to the wall, it should not affect the heating. Expansion and contraction after curing should not be a big issue, I hope, but I see that silicone is apparently the easier way to protect from humidity (at least during the initial phase) and to reduce the stresses later.